# Include debug symbols for an Azure Feed DLL package

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, nuget-package

We have a C# class library that's been published to Azure DevOps as a *.nupkg package feed. We've used this command to create the package:

```
nuget pack SomeProject.csproj -build -properties Configuration=Debug -OutputDirectory c:\_projects\_packages -Symbols -SymbolPackageFormat snupkg
```

We'd like to now publish the `Configuration=Release` version of the package but still be able to debug the solution that uses that feed. We don't use pipelines in Azure DevOps; we only use it as our code repo and to hold our .nupkg packages.

I used the following for Release:

```
nuget pack SomeProject.csproj -build -properties Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory c:\_projects\_packages -Symbols -SymbolPackageFormat snupkg
```

Then I added it to my project. However, when I try to debug, Visual Studio gives this message:

[image]

The above command produces a *.nupkg and a *.snupkg, which both get published to Azure. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/symbols/debug-with-symbols-visual-studio?view=azure-devops#debugging-optimized-modules) little bit of information on debugging Release versions:

> - Open the Modules window, right-click and select Load Symbols (recommended).
> - Select Tools then Options. Select Debugging in the right panel then chose General. uncheck Enable Just My Code.

On the first suggestion, I've gone into the Modules in Debug menu and it's set to automatically load it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I've also added the symbols server:

[image]

What's the implication of the 2nd option: to disable Just My Code?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any issue when you published package to Azure DevOps? It seems your issue is not related to Azure DevOps, but related to Nuget Package.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, no warnings or errors when I called nuget push. It called MSBuild, indicated it was "Pushing", "PUT", "Accepted", with a final "Your package was pushed" message.

Comment: So it seems your issue is not related to Azure DevOps, but related to Nuget Package. You could remove azure-devops tag and add Nuget-package tag.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, thanks. Decided to split the difference and have both tags on the question :)

Comment: If you publish the package to Nuget server, would you be able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, not sure. This is a private package and I can only publish to Azure.